# Remove double and single square brackets from text file generated from python

Tags: python, numpy, text

I have this text file which was generated from python. [Text File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xgn7s3skdxd78x5/ddn140_Stmax.txt?dl=0). I noticed that the data contained in two of the columns are enclosed withing double and single brackets respectively. These two column values were saved as string as were the other columns.

How can I remove these brackets when I import the text file into python.

Thank you,

Comment: Are you saying that you would like to fix the problem when it's being exported or when you import it?

Comment: @Zyneak Since I have already generated the text files, it is better if I can fix it while importing the text file for further analysis. Also If you can point out as to how to fix this issue while writing to the text file, that would also be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: Is your intention to save them as strings? If you're just saving to file in Python to read back into Python then you might consider pickling instead.

Comment: Each row in this text file corresponds to a different text file which is run through a loop and some calculations are made. I am not familiar with pickling. Could you show me an example on how I could use that to remove the brackets?

Comment: Can you show us the code you write to the file with please?

Comment: @Zyneak It is really a long code. I'll see if I can enter the code after removing some things. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to remove all instances of square brackets from a string, you can do the following:

```
s = "[[ hello] [there]]"
s = s.replace("[", "")
s = s.replace("]", "")
```

### UPDATE:

If you want the code to import the file contents, and make the changes:

```
with open('/path/to/my_file.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    text = my_file.read()
    text = text.replace("[", "")
    text = text.replace("]", "")

# If you wish to save the updates back into a cleaned up file
with open('/path/to/my_file_clean.txt', 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write(text)
```

Comment: I am not sure how to use this. I already have a text file with square brackets

Comment: I updated my post to show you how to use it on your file

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked like a charm. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Great! I'm happy it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re 
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+')

with open('someFile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        float_list = " ".join(re.findall(pattern, line))
```

This will only find the parts of the string that match the format number <period> number.

Comment: What do I have to change in the above code to remove the square brackets?

Comment: did you try running the code? float list will give you all of the numbers on the line without any of the square brackets (it removes the square brackets).

Comment: When I run the code with the text file, it is creating a list called float_list with 6 elements. I want to import the file, remove the brackets and do further processing. Could you be more specific? Sorry, I am new to python